# Is there a way to run FirefoxOS with multiple outputs (HDMI devices)

Tags: firefox-os

We are trying to get FirefoxOS to use multiple outputs (HDMI devices) simultaneously in the way to show applications running on either of the screens (presumably different apps on different screens). Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a proof-of-concept demonstration of multiple screen feature on Firefox OS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9QbW-paPZo

You can contact the author for further information.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime we implemented our own proof-of-concept :)